# IOS Testing framework that can run all test then generate a report?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcuitest

I need a advice from you guys. I need a framework to do Automation UITest for IOS Apps. I need to write the tests then to run them all and at the end to give me a report. What can I use to do my tests in this way?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS your best bet is to use the XCUITesting framework from Apple. There is a UI testing section in the apple docs - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest

And there are many good guides online and on youtube.

Comment: I was not sure if XCUITest from Apple offers what I need. But it works ok. Thank you!

Comment: is there any other way to generate the test report for swift?

Comment: Pretty much all frameworks will be able to generate a report. There are also options for getting the report from XCTest. What sort of report do you need to create.